# Entity Framework toList() slow

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i'm using entity framework to select data in a table with ~ 20k records, but i'm doing my select and that's query return ~ 2k records. When I use myEnumerable.ToList()(with 25 records) to use in my gridview this take 10 seconds. I need help.

```
//pageSize = 25;
//ticket have ~ 2k records
//ds enumerable with 25 records
var ds = tickets.Skip(currentRow).Take(pageSize).Select(r => new
        {
            r.NomeServico,
            r.ReferenciaCliente,
            r.DataRegistro,
            r.Codigo,
            r.NomeSolicitante,
            r.ShortStatus,
            r.TipoServico,
            r.Severidade,
            Severidade_min = string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Severidade) ? "" : r.Severidade[0].ToString(),
            CSS_SEVERIDADE = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Severidade)) ? "item_status " + ((r.Severidade == "BAIXA") ? "status_azul" : (r.Severidade == "ALTA") ? "status_vermelho" : "status_laranja") : "",
            CSS_STATUS = Util.GetCssStatus(r.ShortStatus)
        }).AsEnumerable();

        //this method take a few seconds
        var ds1 = ds.ToList();

        gvPainel.DataSource = ds1.OrderBy(t => t.ShortStatus);
        gvPainel.DataBind();
```

What I see is if my table return 20k records or 2k records the ToList() method take the same time to return my list.

Comment: Which is it, LINQ to SQL, or Entity Framework? They are not the same thing. And how is `tickets` defined?

Comment: What does `Util.GetCssStatus(r.ShortStatus) do` is it convertible to  sql query? If is not, probably the linq is getting all the objects and transforming the object in memory, and not in sql. is tickets a DbSet?

Comment: This is Entity Framework. tickets is a IEnumerable<Ticket>. Ticket is a POCO class.

Comment: Util.GetCssStatus(r.ShortStatus) just do a switch/case for return a css class stirng to render in gridview.

Comment: "tickets is a IEnumerable<Ticket>": there's your problem, then. You're retrieving *all* records from the server, and performing your filtering on the client. You're not just reading the 25 rows you want to read.

Comment: Yes, I thought this. Using .Take(25) or not i i'm taking the same time to do .List(). How can I solve this?

Comment: @PedroMontemor @hdv is correct, that's why it seems like the `.ToList()` is taking the same for 20k records or 2k records, because they both have the same amount of records.

Comment: @PedroMontemor you need to do the `.Skip(x)` and `.Take(x)` on the db side, so on your dbset. How are you getting `tickets`?

Comment: In short, you need to deal with `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` for everything that needs to be done server-side, so that `.Skip(m).Take(n)` can be translated into SQL. Don't forget to switch to dealing with `IEnumerable<T>` before calling custom methods such as `Util.GetCssStatus` though.

Comment: I need take all records from table to filter in the server the users parameters. When I use Stopwatch to monitor the time ellapsed the filter is fast, but toList() is slow with or nor without 25object in my Enumerator. I don't think if is possible, but i think even my enumerator with 25 object causes tolist scroll 20k records.

Comment: @hvd I'll try IQueryable<T>. Thanks

Comment: @hvd Thanks man! That's work fine! If you lived in Brazil i would go to you and give um a strong hug! hahaha... i was trying solve this to 2 weeks

Comment: For future reference, if you ran this trace through QueryAnalizer or some other monitor, you should have seen that the query didn't include your filters/paging which could have helped narrow down the issue. at least you learned the hard way the difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable.